# SCTP one-to-many in Java

Tags: java, sctp

I'm working in Java to create a one-to-many connection using Java and SCTP protocol.

I've gotten a SctpMultiChannel up and running and I can receive messages, but is there something special needed to be done to send a message to all connections?

```
The error message:

java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument
    at sun.nio.ch.SctpChannelImpl.send0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SctpMultiChannelImpl.send0(SctpMultiChannelImpl.java:976)
    at sun.nio.ch.SctpMultiChannelImpl.sendFromNativeBuffer(SctpMultiChannelImpl.java:888)
    at sun.nio.ch.SctpMultiChannelImpl.send(SctpMultiChannelImpl.java:847)
    at sun.nio.ch.SctpMultiChannelImpl.send(SctpMultiChannelImpl.java:824)
    at org.test.MultiServer.run(MultiServer.java:56)
```

And the complete code:

```
SocketAddress serverSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(SOCKET_PORT);
    SctpMultiChannel smc;
    try {
      Logger.info("Start");
      smc = SctpMultiChannel.open().bind(serverSocketAddress);

      ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(160);
      Charset charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
      CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();

      AssociationHandler assocHandler = new AssociationHandler();

      MessageInfo messageInfo;
      while ((messageInfo = smc.receive(buf, System.out, assocHandler)) != null) {
        Logger.debug(messageInfo.toString());
        buf.flip();
        Logger.debug(decoder.decode(buf).toString());
        Logger.info(smc.associations().size() + "");

        ByteBuffer buf1 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(60);
        CharBuffer cbuf1 = CharBuffer.allocate(60);
        charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
        CharsetEncoder encoder = charset.newEncoder();
        cbuf1.put("foo").flip();
        encoder.encode(cbuf1, buf1, true);
        buf1.flip();

        for (Association ass : smc.associations()) {
          MessageInfo mi = MessageInfo.createOutgoing(ass, null, 1);
          smc.send(buf, mi);
        }
        cbuf1.clear();
        buf1.clear();
        buf1.flip();
      }
      smc.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Logger.error("Server error");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is what I've done so far, my client sends a message and is then going to wait to receive a new message.
What I'm aiming for is to have a non-blocking approach so I can send and receive messages on the same channel, and not blockint with the receive query.

Anyone got any experience in this?

best,
Henrik

Comment: Added the error in the question.

Answer (score 0):

From the error I can say that the MessageInfo is not correct. Try sending only one message without looping. Set the address statically.

Also the first send establishes the connection in case of SctpMultiChannel - how are you able to loop over the associations since they are not established? Is this the whole code?